# How to check a checkbox from dataset my code attached ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to check `checkbox` from `dataset` as I have values in dataset are like,

```
USERNAME     Permissions
Charles     
John         Insert, View
Tom          View
```

how would I check check box I tried it like

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkView" Checked='<%#bool.Parse(Eval("permissions").ToString() == "View" ? "True": "False") %>' runat="server" />View
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkInsert" Checked='<%#bool.Parse (Eval("permissions").ToString() == "Insert" ? "True": "False") %>' runat="server" />Insert
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkUpdate" Checked='<%#bool.Parse (Eval("permissions").ToString() == "Update" ? "True": "False") %>' runat="server" />Update
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkDelete" Checked='<%#bool.Parse (Eval("permissions").ToString() == "Delete" ? "True": "False") %>' runat="server" />Delete
```

but permission has value either with comma how would we split it

Hopes for your suggestion

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Contains instead of ==

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkView" Checked='<%#bool.Parse(Eval("permissions").ToString().Contains("View") ? "True": "False") %>' runat="server" />View
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkInsert" Checked='<%#bool.Parse (Eval("permissions").ToString().Contains("Insert") ? "True": "False") %>' runat="server" />Insert
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkUpdate" Checked='<%#bool.Parse (Eval("permissions").ToString().Contains("Update") ? "True": "False") %>' runat="server" />Update
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkDelete" Checked='<%#bool.Parse (Eval("permissions").ToString().Contains("Delete") ? "True": "False") %>' runat="server" />Delete
```